How can I redirect a PDF file to another page?
I created EventSubscriber in my custom module; however, my code is not working. Can anyone tell me how to use EventSubscriber for redirection?
Path: /sites/default/files/test.pdf
To be redirected: /login
Code:
namespace Drupal\custom_redirect\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class CustomRedirectSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  /**
   * Responds to the kernel request event to handle PDF redirection.
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent $event
   *   The event to process.
   */
  public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event) {
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $path = $request->getPathInfo();

    // Check if the request is for a PDF file.
    if (preg_match('/\.pdf$/', $path)) {
      // Define the target URL for the redirection.
      $new_url = '/new-pdf-location'; // Change this to the actual URL you want to redirect to.

      // Create a redirect response.
      $response = new RedirectResponse($new_url);
      $event->setResponse($response);
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return [
      KernelEvents::REQUEST => ['onKernelRequest', 0],
    ];
  }
}


In Drupal, the public file folder is not controlled by Drupal; it is directly delivered through the web server. So, I think this is the reason your event subscriber is not working.
You have to move the file to the private file system, and then Drupal can control access to the file and redirect it.

Hi @Munish Kumar, thank you for answering, however, I tried using the private file.
$settings['file_private_path'] = 'sites/default/private';
PDF URL: /sites/default/private/test.pdf
But the above code doesn't work. Thank you

Explaining the private file system is outside this question.
